# Invoking a method that contain a throw InterruptedException from a separate method from a different class

Tags: java

I'm attempting to code a program in which there are separate classes and methods from each of those classes cross-calling methods from other classes. Below is a coded method that I wanted to call from another method from another class.

```
public class walk{
    public void walk() throws InterruptedException {
        Printer printer = new Printer();
        printer.start();
    }
}
```

Here is how it is being called by another method in the separate class.

```
public class Runner{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        walk w1 = new walk();
        w1.walk();
    }
}
```

The error that pops up is error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown and it states that the problem is with the following line of code.

```
w1.walk();
```

Does anyone know how to invoke this method from a separate class or am I doing something else wrong with public void line?

Comment: are you getting an error/exception? Has walkStopWatch been created somewhere else?

Comment: walkStopWatch is created prior in the program. I was just wondering how to invoke this method from another class and the error I keep getting is that the w1.walk() is missing something when I do invoke it.

Comment: You can import the class that has methods into the class where you want to run and then create the object of those class to run the method. If the method is static you can also call directly by using ClassName.MethodName();

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: @jzhong653 "It says that I'm missing something in the code line" could you give us the exact error? We need more details for this problem

Comment: The error message you now show you receive already describes your two options for fixing the problem.  What prevents you from choosing one and implementing it?

Comment: @jzhong653 try surrounding `w1.walk()` with a `try/catch` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) does not extend RuntimeException, you have to handle the declared exception using the try-catch block when calling `walk()`:

```
try {
    w1.walk();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Handle exception, e.g. log it or notify the user.
}
```

Another solution is to declare the exception in the method signature of the calling method using throws:

```
public void x() throws InterupptedException
    walk w1 = new walk();
    w1.walk();
}
```

The second approach is viable when you want to pass exception handling to the caller of your method. You could declare the main-method to throw exceptions, but imho the main-method should catch even non-recoverable exceptions and atleast log them.

The [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) can give you some guidance when dealing with exceptions, my adive would be to read the [Catch or Specify Requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) and get familiar with the three kinds of exceptions in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Task extends Thread
{
  public void run() 
  {
   int time = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      time ++;
      if(time == 9)
      {
        System.out.println("\nBOOM!");
        break;
      }
      try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Issue");
      //This can be anything to let the user/programmer know something's wrong
    }
  
    }
  }
}
```

So if you are trying to throw exceptions, I would suggest doing this. This is a sample where I print "BOOM!" the timer for the bomb (For loop) is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you:

```
public class ClassA {

        //Static Method
    public static void MethodA() {
        System.out.println("Method A running");
    }

}

public class ClassB {

    public  void MethodB() {
        System.out.println("Method B running");
    }

}
```

//THIS IS THE RUNNER CLASS main class which runs your methods

```
 public class MainClass {



        public static void main (String args[]){




            //Invoking method from ClassB
            ClassB b = new ClassB();
            b.MethodB();

    //Invoking method from ClassA
            ClassA.MethodA();

        }
```